# i was usin node and try to work with socket but getting error again and again

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets

HER MY CODE IS :
IN app.js or SERVER CODE

```
var express = require("express");
var app= express();
var http = require("http");
var http = require("http");
var server= http.createServer(app);
var port = 5000 || process.env.PORT;
var socket= require("socket.io").listen(server);
var path = require("path")
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname+"/public")))

app.get("/", (req, res)=>{
res.sendFile(__dirname+"/index.html");
});
 socket.on("connection", (socket)=>{
console.log("SOCKET IS CONNECTED")
})


server.listen(port, ()=>{
console.log(`connected at port no: ${port}`)
})
```

//IN INDEX.HTML

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/main.js"></script>

 i have also tried 


<script src="http://localhost:5000/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script src="/js/main.js"></script>
```

//IN MAIN.JS

```
var socket = io("http://localhost:5000");
```

but getting this error :

VM554:5551 crbug/1173575, non-JS module files deprecated.

in network tab i got "FAILED TO LOAD RESPOND DATA"

and in this directory i could not find socket.io.js:

C:\Users\pc\Desktop\socket\back\node_modules\socket.io\client-dist

can anyone help me plzz i was trying to figure it out for 2 days